# How to manage Firebase database security rules for Sign In for the first time when there is no user registered yet?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

This is my database Rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
    // document. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
    // available in rules.
    match /user/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null; 
    }
    
    match /user/{userId} {
      allow create, read, write, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    
    match /{document=**} {
      allow create, read, write, update, delete: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see user must have to get an `auth.uid` to get access into the `documents` of my database.

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow create, read, write, update, delete: if request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

But the problem is when I have no user registered on my Authentication (And in Document `/user/{userId}`) and somebody try to sign in, I can not get any response for the limitation of permission. How should I set my security rules where I can check if a user actually exists or not in Sign In process?

P.S: It's working perfectly if I have at least one user registered on my auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the suggestion of Doug Stevenson, I removed `request.auth.uid` from `/user/{userId}` and erase `read` from same node on the next check and it is working.
Thanks a lot.

Full answer is:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
    // document. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
    // available in rules.
    match /user/{userId} {
      allow read; 
    }

    match /user/{userId} {
      allow create, write, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

    match /{document=**} {
      allow create, read, write, update, delete: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Security rules don't know or care if there are any users registered with your app.  They just make requirements about how the data can be accessed.  If your rules require a signed-in user, then that's the requirement - there's no getting around it.

If some of your data must be accessible without being signed in, then you can't have a requirement that `request.auth` be populated with user data.